# Using Repository class object across multiple threads

Tags: spring, java-8, spring-data-jpa

I have been using a repository object like below in a single threaded application till now.

```
@Service
class MyEntityService {
    @Autowired
    private MyEntityRepository repository;
}
```

The repository looks like below -

```
import com.myorg.mypackage.entities.facebook.MyEntity;
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
public interface MyEntityRepository extends CrudRepository<MyEntity, String> {
    MyEntity findByFacebookPageId(String facebookPageId);
}
```

I plan to start using multiple threads via Executor service and write to database concurrently. Do I need to create multiple instances of the repository or a single one will do?

Comment: each of these methods from a repository is implicitly annotated with `Transactional` - a separate transaction is spanned for each of your requests - and this is what you should care about. to me (if that's all the code that you are showing) - you are on the safe side, *especially* since all you are doing is a read here

Comment: They're threadsafe - but you need to handle context somehow. Ideally you bind a connection/session to each thread so that you don't check one out of the pool each time. There is also a question of what you want to do with the transactions - having one open and close every method call will be rather slow - depending on what you are doing, it may well make your multi-threaded code rather ... serial.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally speaking, spring jpa is thread safe. It all comes from the entity manager which is obtained from the entity manager factories in spring. Spring injects a new entity manager in each thread so it makes the entity manager look thread safe.

check this nice [article](https://www.isostech.com/blogs/software-development/jpa-spring-data-awesomeness/)

Comment: EntityManagerFactory is thread safe. EntityManager is not thread-safe